# TFS Silverlight 4 problem

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, tfs

We use **TFS 2010** as our source control and **VS 2010** as IDE. We have a problem when we add a silverlight4 MVVM project to the TFS. The problem is that project builds on all machines but runs only on the machine which is created on. On other machines it ends up with this message:

**The Silverlight project you are about to debug uses WCF RIA services. WCF RIA services will fail unless the Silverlight project is hosted in and from the same web project that contains the WCF RIA services.**

Answer (score 0):

The service that your silverlight application will connect to has to be in the same web application that hosts your silverlight XAP.
Confirm a few things here:

1. Make sure the .proj file of your
   silverlight app has a link to your
   RIA service (in project settings)
2. Make sure that when you compile, an
   assembly with the name of your RIA service is created in the bin
   directory of your hosting web project
3. Try accessing the RIA service in
   your browser.  The path should be
   something like:
   http://yourLocalUrl(locaholhost:1234)/assembly-name-webdomainservicename.svc
   You must replace all . by - in the
   assemblyname. eg:
   http://localhost:1234/my-assembly-name-testWebDomainService.svc
   You can disassembly your dll of the your silverlight app and look inside to see the URI

Good luck